# Need validation for numerical number with special charecter in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this script for only numerical number script is given below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $('#phone').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    var node = $(this);
    node.val(node.val().replace(/[^0-9]/g,'') ); }
    );

  </script>
```

using this when i tried to enter any charcter on this text filled this validation not allowd me to type charecter it support only numerical number but i want extra and special charecter to allow with this script can any one have idea about this please help me about this i am stuck here ...

Comment: Which extra _special_ character(s) you want to allow?

Comment: Add the special character to `[^0-9]`

Comment: yes i want to allow with special charecter and numerical numbers only @31piy

Comment: Please clearly specify in question some examples of expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your special character to the regular expression `/[^0-9-+]/g`.  This allows `+` and `-` to the input field

check the snippet

```js
$('#phone').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    var node = $(this);
    node.val(node.val().replace(/[^0-9-+@#]/g,'') ); }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="phone">
```

Comment: @Shruti, you need to add that character to the regular Expression, I will update, check the snippet

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a way to just remove alphabets but not special chars and numbers.
here's how I think you can do that,

```
$('#phone').bind('keyup blur',function(){ 
    var node = $(this);
    node.val(node.val().replace(/[a-z]/gi, '')); 
});
```

Explanation:

```
/[a-z] - will look for patters with alphabets
/gi - `g` will look for global (replace all calls with matches) and `i` means ignore case
```